# Meaning of $\inf$ in proof of fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

$f = a_0 + a_1x+..+a_nx^n \in \Bbb C[x] $, $\deg(f)\geq1$
$$\mu = \inf(|f(z)|,z\in \Bbb C[x])$$

I am reading proof of fundamental theorem of algebra and can't understand this part.$|f(z)|$ is a number yes?How can we define $inf$ of number.Sorry if it is silly question.

Comment: Yes sorry for wrong notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any given $z\in \Bbb C$, yes, $|f(z)|$ is a non-negative real number. However, that number is not what were $\inf$-ing. We are $\inf$-ing the set of all possible values $|f(z)|$ can take, for all possible $z\in \Bbb C$. That's what
$$
(|f(z)|,z\in\Bbb C)
$$
refers to: all possible values, not one arbitrary value. It is more conventional to use curly brackets for this, rather than round. But it's clear either way.

And I strongly suspect that's a typo in your $\inf$. We have $f\in \Bbb C[x]$, but when evaluating $f(z)$, the $z$ comes from $\Bbb C$.